# @RenderBody() with canvas

Tags: c#, html, razor, model-view-controller

I have a canvas loaded onto the `_Layout.cshtml`

When I browse from the Index page, to About or Contact, the `<canvas>` is showing but the page content is missing.

`Index` page will load a `div` under `<body>` tag but `About` page is missing content.

I'm assuming `@RenderBody` isn't in the appropriate z-index or is not showing on top of `<canvas>` like my Index page does.

```
<canvas id="bgCanvas"></canvas>
<script src="~/Scripts/starLayout.js"></script>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

edit2:

under view source it shows

```
    <canvas id="bgCanvas"></canvas>
    <script src="/Scripts/starLayout.js"></script>

    <div class="container body-content">


<h2>About.</h2>
<h3>Your application description page.</h3>
<div>
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
</div>
        <hr />


        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 4/17/2015 11:33:17 AM - JTR</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

However I still can't see the content so it's underneath the canvas I believe. Which is weird since it is on top of the canvas on `index.cshtml`

Comment: What is `starLayout.js` doing? Maybe it's breaking the page rendering. Also, `_Layout.cshtml` doesn't look like a complete HTML document.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite clear. Are you saying that `@RenderBody()` is injecting content but not the content you expect, or is the content not there? When you say "the page content is missing" do you mean it's not in the DOM (not there when you view source) or that it's not _visible_?

Comment: Oh good point. When I view source It's there just not visible.

Comment: yeah i think this is just a html / css issue. i bleieve all `<canvas>` elements are supposed to have `height` and `width` specified. so the default value might be covering up your other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer: [w3c canvas](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/). Shortly, you must provide width and height properties for canvas element.

And remember to place the *.js file/code which is responsible for "drawing" after the canvas element.

Can you provide css code, so I'll be abe to edit this answer to be more specific?